# How to restore previous LVM volume group configuration?

Tags: data-recovery, lvm

I try to recover from disk crash, and while doing so, I make a mistake -- now I have to recover from two things.

So the first is recovering previous LVM configuration file for volumne group -- I have the desired file, but I when I run:

```
vgcfgrestore my_vol_group
```

I get error:

> Couldn't find device with uuid
>   jJ7dXL-2m2j-d0OC-bczy-fQak-YOj7-OhRLlW.   Cannot restore Volume Group
>   my_vol_group with 1 PVs marked as missing.   Restore failed.

Which is of course true, because this disk is one that crashed. So how to restore config despite the fact I am returning to the "corrupted" scenario anyway? Something like "force restore"?

**Update**: timeline what happened:

1. three disks in one LVM group -- I am happy
2. one of the disk crashes
3. I removed the faulty disk from my computer
4. I wanted to remove it from LVM and repair what was left
5. by mistake I removed entire LV which contained faulty disk
6. I want to go back to (4)

Comment: @rudimeier, thank you. Yes, I wanted to remove it from logical volume as well, instead entire LV was removed from the group too. So now I want to undo this removal. As for `pvcreate` I assume the filename is the one with the previous LVM config? All I get is error message: "Can only set uuid on one volume at once".

Comment: @rudimeier, I am sorry for not being clear, I updated the question. I don't have this faulty disk in computer, since it crashed (it does not work at all). I only have the disks which work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would try it like this

1. Add a new disk at least as big as the missing one (say  /dev/sdX).
2. Create a PV with same uuid as the missing one.

   pvcreate --restorefile YOUR-FILE --uuid J7dXL-2m2j-d0OC-bczy-fQak-YOj7-OhRLlW   /dev/sdX
3. Try again your restore command:

   vgcfgrestore  --restorefile YOUR-FILE my_vol_group

See also `man vgcfgrestore`:

> *REPLACING PHYSICAL VOLUMES*
>          vgdisplay --partial --verbose will show you the UUIDs and sizes of any PVs that are no longer present.  If a PV in the VG is lost and you wish to  substitute  another  of  the  same  size,  use  pvcreate
>          --restorefile  filename  --uuid  uuid (plus additional arguments as appropriate) to initialise it with the same UUID as the missing PV.  Repeat for all other missing PVs in the VG.  Then use vgcfgrestore
>          --file filename to restore the volume group's metadata.

Comment: Thank you again. I don't have any replacement (especially equal in size) and I will not be replacing the faulty disk. I just want repair and mount what is left. For now all I want to do is restore previous configuration file. Just to test something I tried smaller disk (pendrive), however I get error "Couldn't find device with uuid jJ7dXL-2m2j-d0OC-bczy-fQak-YOj7-OhRLlW"

Comment: You could manually edit the restore file with text editor, it's not that hard. Remove all LV definitions which would use the missing PV and remove the missing PV definition. **Or** you could use a sparse fake device: `truncate -s 1024G /tmp/BIGFILE; losetup /dev/loop1 /tmp/BIGFILE `

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! :-) Finally. I removed the entries as you wrote, and recalculated the `start_extent` counts, to make the numbers go linear (without a gap caused by removed drive).

Comment: By "YOUR-FILE", rudimeier means a file one can find in `/etc/lvm/archive/`. So the pvcreate command would look something like `pvcreate --restorefile /etc/lvm/archive/my_vol_group_00008.vg --uuid ...`